# SELECT statistics with max entries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `clients`:

```
Id | utm_term | goal | region |
 1 |    a     |  aa  |  ccc   |
 2 |    b     |  aa  |  bbb   |
 3 |    c     |  bb  |  aaa   |
 4 |    b     |  cc  |  ccc   |
```

I need select `count` of clients, `utm_term` with max entries, `goal` with max entries and `region` with max entries.

In output it's supposed to be:

```
Count | utm_term | goal | region |
  4   |    b     |  aa  |  ccc   |
```

I'm using `mysql` but in ideal I want non-platform solution.

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: What is your effort ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a query like:

```
SELECT (
         SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM clients
       ) AS Count,
       (
         SELECT utm_term
           FROM ( SELECT utm_term, COUNT(*) as count1
                    FROM clients
                GROUP BY utm_term
                ) AS s1
         ORDER BY count1 DESC
         LIMIT 1
       ) AS utm_term,
       (
         SELECT goal
           FROM ( SELECT goal, COUNT(*) as count1
                    FROM clients
                GROUP BY goal
                ) AS s2
         ORDER BY count1 DESC
         LIMIT 1
       ) AS goal,
       (
         SELECT region
           FROM ( SELECT region, COUNT(*) as count1
                    FROM clients
                GROUP BY region
                ) AS s3
         ORDER BY count1 DESC
         LIMIT 1
       ) AS goal
```

Comment: Well, it has some queries, true, but they are simple enough. So, if you have the right indexes it should be fast.